# Redirect WordPress website URL into other link

Tags: redirect, htaccess

In wordpress website multi domain point one wordpress.

1. domain1.com
2. domina2.com

Redirect URL is : domain3.com

I have try using htaccess file .

```
Redirect domina2.com  domain3.com
```

but it is not working. so I try

```
Redirect /index.html  domain3.com
```

so it is redirecting both websites to domain3.com.

how to solve it.

I am okay with that if the solution uses index.php so direct put code on it working.

Comment: How about `Redirect domina2.com/index.php  domain3.com` ?

Comment: @prosti I have tried it but not working.